# setTimeout() syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble getting the following setTimeouts to work:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    if( last ) {
        if( ($(this).attr('id') == last.attr('id')) ) {
            setTimeout( function(){ 
                $(this).parent().parent().css('visibility','hidden'); 
            },500); 
            setTimeout( function(){ 
                last.parent().parent().css('visibility','hidden'); 
            },500); 
            found++; 
        } 
        if (found == 3) { 
            alert('You won a sticker!'); 
            window.location.href = "#play2"; 
            location.reload(); //resets found to 0 
        } last = null; 
    } 
    else { 
        last = $(this) 
    } 
});
```

The functions inside the setTimeout work so that it not the problem. I am wondering if there is something wrong with my syntax. I can't find anything wrong with it, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first `setTimeout` `this === window`. You'd probably want to create a closure

```
var that = this
setTimeout( function(){
    $(that).parent().parent().css('visibility','hidden');
 },500);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem with the `setTimeout()` syntax. The problem is that within a function `this` is set depending on how that function is called, and when you call your function via `setTimeout()` then `this` is no longer the DOM element from your click event. You can keep a reference to it *outside* the function you pass to `setTimeout()`, which could also save you selecting `$(this)` twice (if you use the saved reference both in your function and in the `if` statement). I don't see anything wrong with the second `setTimeout()` since it already uses a reference from outside the function.

```
    var $this = $(this);
    if( ($this.attr('id') == last.attr('id')) ) {
        setTimeout( function(){ 
            $this.parent().parent().css('visibility','hidden'); 
        },500); 
        setTimeout( function(){ 
            last.parent().parent().css('visibility','hidden'); 
        },500); 
        found++; 
    }
```

Alternatively if you use `.hide()` then you can use jQuery's animation queue to `.delay()` things rather than `setTimeout()`:

```
    $(this).parent().parent().delay(500).hide(1);
```

Makes for neater code, but `.hide()` will set `display:none` rather than `visibility:hidden` and I acknowledge that that might not be what you want (you can't use `.delay()` with `.css()` because `.css()` is not an animation method).

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this` inside the `click` handler is a reference to the element that was clicked. The value of `this` inside the callback to `setTimeout` is the global `window` object. The key point is that **the value of `this` inside a function is contextual** (i.e. it is dependant on **how the function was invoked**).

You need to save a reference to the value of `this` from the outer scope so that you can use it inside the inner scope:

```
if ($(this).attr('id') == last.attr('id')) {
    var that = $(this);
    setTimeout( function() { 
        that.parent().parent().css('visibility','hidden'); 
    },500); 
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery idioms:

```
setTimeout(jQuery.proxy(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().css('visibility','hidden');
}, this), 500);
```

Standard JavaScript:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().css('visibility','hidden');
}.bind(this), 500);
```